# How does this while loop evaluate the condition to be true or false?

Tags: ruby

I created the following code to do the bubble sort and the code worked out fine. My question is why it worked... When the method is called, I assume the computer will first evaluate whether $x is equal to 0. But I haven't assigned value to $x to begin with, so what makes the computer start to run the each loop?

It seems to have something to do with the fact that x is a global variable, but I am not sure how. Please suggest!

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    while $x != 0
        $x = 0
        arr.each_with_index do |i, j|
            if arr[j+1] != nil && i > arr[j+1]
            arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
            $x += 1
            end
        end
    end
    arr
end

p bubble_sort([4,3,78,2,0,5,100,34])
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `x` being a global variable.  It *does* have to do with you *having* that variable, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're invoking the method only once? ...

The global $x doesn't exist during the first call and the search for that global variable returns `nil`.

Hence, the first `while` loop evaluates `$x==0` as `nil == 0` which is `false`.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, this is what happened... while evaluates whether $x is 0 or not. Since I have not assigned any value to $x at the beginning, nil is returned as the value for $x. Since nil is not equal to 0, while evaluates the condition to be true, and therefore the each loop runs.

Comment: @JoeyLi  , exactly.